# Convergence $\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{a_k}{ \sum_{i=0}^k a_{i}^2} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, sequence-of-function

I am trying to see whether or not this series converges for $a_k>0,k\geq 0$ and $\sum_k a_k^2 < \infty$.

When $a_k \geq 1$, I have this bound:
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{a_k}{\sum_{i=0}^k a_{i}^2} &\leq \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{a_k^2}{\sum_{i=0}^k a_{i}^2}\\
    &= \sum_{k=1}^N \int_{\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a_{i}^2}^{\sum_{i=0}^{k} a_{i}^2}\frac{1}{\sum_{i=0}^{k} a_{i}^2}dx\\
    &\leq \sum_{k=1}^N \int_{\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a_{i}^2}^{\sum_{i=0}^{k} a_{i}^2}\frac{1}{x}dx\\
    &= \int_{a_0^2}^{\sum_{i=0}^{N} a_{i}^2}\frac{1}{x}dx
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: For $a_n=1$ you get the (divergent) harmonic series.

Comment: you're right but I forgot this condition $\sum_k a_k^2 < \infty$. That excludes this case.

Comment: Let $a_k=1/k$. Now what?..

Comment: It's divergent in that case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k^2=S>0$. Denote 
$$
b_k:=\frac{a_k}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}a_i^2}.
$$
Then, 
$$
b_k\sim\frac{a_k}{S},~\text{when}~n\to\infty.
$$
Hence, ($a_k, b_k>0$) the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}b_k$ is convergent if and only if the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}{a_k}$ is convergent. Moreover, note that if $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ is convergent, then so is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k^2$.